# how to dynamically update editbox of matlab gui before saving in .mat

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, editbox

I am quite new with the MATLAB gui and I wandered how we could allow an editbox value to be modified once the callback to the corresponding function had already been done (ie once the value is entered inside the editbox).

Indeed I would like to save (with a pushbutton) the LAST data entered in my editbox in case the user modifies it before saving, not the first value entered for the first time.

Thanks in advance,

CODE SAMPLE:

```
function Data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

data = get(handles.data,'String');   %import value from editbox
data = str2double (data);
handles.Data = data;


function Save_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

save('DATA.mat','data');             %save it in .mat file
close; clear all; clc
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback of the text-box is excecuted, if the users changes the text within the text-box. There seems to be just one thing missing in your save-fcn:

you have to get the value from the handles-structure:

```
function Save_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
data=handles.data;
save('DATA.mat','data');             %save it in .mat file
%I would suggest to leave out the clear all and clc-commands...
```